# ST_transform postgis

Tags: postgis, google-maps, spatial-database, postgis-2.0, google-maps-api

SQL within that zone is a point

```
SELECT
    "public".zona.zts
FROM
    "public".zona
WHERE
    ST_Within (
        ST_Transform (
            ST_GeomFromText (
                'POINT(-30.033514 -51.226828)',
                4326
            ),
            3857
        ),
        zona.geom
    );
```

I tested in a single step and in separate steps. But the result is always no record. 
This pair of coordinates of the point I'm getting via google maps api in a single page geocode addresses, this is my geocode:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Geocoding Simple</title>
    <link href="https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&v=3.2"></script> 


    <script>
      var geocoder;
      var map;
      var mapOptions = {
          zoom: 17,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
      var marker;

      function initialize() {
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);
        codeAddress();
      }

      function codeAddress() {
        var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            if(marker)
              marker.setMap(null);
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location,
                draggable: true
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "dragend", function() {
              document.getElementById('lat').value = marker.getPosition().lat();
              document.getElementById('lng').value = marker.getPosition().lng();
            });
            document.getElementById('lat').value = marker.getPosition().lat();
            document.getElementById('lng').value = marker.getPosition().lng();
          } else {
            alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
          }
        });
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="initialize()">
    <div>
      <input id="address" type="textbox" style="width:60%" value="Rua Joao Neves da Fontoura,7-Porto Alegre">
      <input type="button" value="Geocode" onclick="codeAddress()">
      <input type="text" id="lat"/>
      <input type="text" id="lng"/>

    </div>
    <div id="map_canvas" style="height:60%;top:30px"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

She gives me coordinates in decimal degrees and my postgis table is in UTM EPSG: 3857 how can I do this conversion? The way I did in the above sql does not work. 
Out of curiosity I have sinned a point of a polygon that forms a zone and put as parâmentro and it worked.

Comment: misspelled - should be: ST_Within()

Comment: Corrected the error but returns no value and made ​​sure that this point is inside a zone. What can be causing this problem? My table areas are in EPSG: 3857 and the point I turned to ESPG: 3857 too.

Comment: You've forgotten to assign the coordinate system to the point. You can do it all in one step, like this: SELECT "public".zona.zts FROM "public".zona WHERE ST_Within ( ST_Transform (ST_GeomFromText ('POINT(-30.033514 -51.226828)',4326),3857), zona.geom );

Comment: I edited the question it did not work my sql.

Comment: OK, let's simplify the sql statement and use ST_Intersects() instead of ST_Within(). Remember the order of your coordinates is 'POINT( latitude longitude )'. You need to specify columns to return from your query ( * ). This works for me: SELECT column_name FROM table_name WHERE ST_Intersects( ST_GeomFromText('POINT(35 -75)',4326), geom_column_name) LIMIT 1;

Comment: Still does not return me any results, I corrected the coordinates of the longitude and latitude format. The coordinates returned by google maps api are different from my EPS format: 3857. How can I convert coordinates in decimal degrees using postgis?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14996/discussion-between-mtn-biker-and-cassia-freitas).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on Kevin's answer - except WKT point coordinates are separated by a space, not a comma:

```
SELECT ST_AsText (ST_Transform (ST_GeomFromText ('POINT(-30.033514 -51.226828)',4326),3857)) AS wgs_geom;
```

Comment: Ha thanks @mtn.biker! I just noticed that myself. Added as an edit to my answer above.

Comment: Thanks! I edited the question about the function ST_Within I need to consult within that region is this point that I created ... can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

instead of `POINT((-30.033514, -51.226828))`, try `POINT(-30.033514 -51.226828)`. WKT for points doesn't need a double set of parentheses, and shouldn't have commas between values. See [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text) entry for WKT for more info.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT
    ST_AsText (
        ST_Transform (
            ST_GeomFromText (
                'POINT(-30.033514 -51.226828)',
                4326
            ),
            3857
        )
    ) AS wgs_geom`